# ActionView::MissingTemplate:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, post, spree

Running a Spree extension that connects Spree 3.4 to ShipStation.

Orders are received by ShipStation perfectly fine via an XML GET request, but when the tracking number is sent back to the Spree store from ShipStation via XML POST an error is logged as below.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template spree/shipstation/shipnotify, spree/base/shipnotify, application/shipnotify with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :rabl], :versions=>[:v1]}. Searched in:
```

The Spree extension can be viewed on GitHub: https://github.com/MatthewKennedy/spree_shipstation
Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this error?

(The tracking number is added to the order correctly but I would like to solve this error).

Comment: Why haven't you created a shipnotify.xml.builder view file ?

Comment: The issue is fixed now.